# Modify Windows Login screen

Tags: c#, authentication

Is it possble to Modify the Window's Login screen and add our own buttons/links? For example is it possible to do something like this?

[alt text http://www.allaboutmoss.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/windowsxp_login.jpg](http://www.allaboutmoss.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/windowsxp_login.jpg)

The above screen has a link and when clicked it should start a win forms application?

Comment: Back in the days of NT the company I worked for did a custom replacement of the windows login screen (not adding buttons, but a complete replacement) and I assume it can still be done

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For Windows XP, you can build a [GINA DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380543%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), and for Vista+ you need to use the new [credential providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc163489.aspx) system. In both cases, you basically have to build the UI from scratch and so it's not really possible to just take the existing UI and add a few controls here and there.

Of course, you could build your own GINA DLL that displays UI that's the same as the standard Windows XP one, with your own additions, but it's not exactly a simple task.

Comment: Is it possible to build a Gina dll or a credential provider in .NET?

Comment: You can't build the DLL itself in .NET (it has to export functions, which you can't do in C#) but I'm pretty sure you could write a C++ wrapper that calls C# code to do the actual work.